# STIG'd RedHat 8 kills tmux session upon SSH timeout

Tags: ssh, redhat, rhel8, tmux, compliance

I am working on a Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) 8 machine with the DISA STIG applied via OpenSCAP. The STIG requires that users be automatically dropped into a tmux session, that tmux session locks the screen after a set idle time, and SSH disconnects after another amount of idle time.

The problem I'm having is that we have long running commands that we start and then walk away from. First tmux locks the screen, and eventually SSH kills the connection. The expected behavior is that when we reconnect via SSH either the old tmux session is reconnected or a new tmux session is created while the old one is still running in the background. Either way we don't want the tmux session to die when SSH disconnects.

The relevant STIGs and our configurations are as follows:

https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_8/2023-09-11/finding/V-230349

```
$ cat /etc/profile.d/tmux.sh
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  parent=$(ps -o ppid= -p $$)
  name=$(ps -o comm= -p $parent)
  case "$name" in (sshd|login) tmux ;; esac
fi
if [ -n "$TMUX" ]; then
  # render /etc/issue or else fall back to kernel/system info
  agetty --show-issue 2>/dev/null || uname -a

  # message of the day
  for motd in /run/motd.dynamic /etc/motd; do
    if [ -s "$motd" ]; then cat "$motd"; break; fi
  done

  # last login
  last $USER |awk 'NR==2 {
    if (NF==10) { i=1; if ($3!~/^:/) from = " from " $3 }
    printf("Last login: %s %s %s %s%s on %s\n",
      $(3+i), $(4+i), $(5+i), $(6+i), from, $2);
    exit
  }'

  # mail check
  if [ -s "/var/mail/$USER" ] # may need to change to /var/spool/mail/$USER
    then echo "You have  mails."
    else echo "You have no mail."
  fi
fi
```

https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_8/2023-09-11/finding/V-230353

```
$ cat /etc/tmux.conf
set -g lock-after-time 300
set -g lock-command vlock
bind X lock-session
```

https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/red_hat_enterprise_linux_8/2023-09-11/finding/V-244525

```
$ cat /etc/ssh/sshd_config
...
Compression no
ClientAliveInterval 600
ClientAliveCountMax 1
#UseDNS no
...
```

I also suspect systemd-logind has something to do with it due to [this argument](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=825394) on the Debian mailing list.

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/logind.conf
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#
# Entries in this file show the compile time defaults.
# You can change settings by editing this file.
# Defaults can be restored by simply deleting this file.
#
# See logind.conf(5) for details.

[Login]
StopIdleSessionSec=900
#NAutoVTs=6
#ReserveVT=6
KillUserProcesses=no
#KillOnlyUsers=
#KillExcludeUsers=root
#InhibitDelayMaxSec=5
#HandlePowerKey=poweroff
#HandleSuspendKey=suspend
#HandleHibernateKey=hibernate
#HandleLidSwitch=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchExternalPower=suspend
#HandleLidSwitchDocked=ignore
#PowerKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#SuspendKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#HibernateKeyIgnoreInhibited=no
#LidSwitchIgnoreInhibited=yes
#HoldoffTimeoutSec=30s
#IdleAction=ignore
#IdleActionSec=30min
#RuntimeDirectorySize=10%
#RemoveIPC=no
#InhibitorsMax=8192
#SessionsMax=8192
#StopIdleSessionSec=infinity
```

I edited longer files to give the relevant sections.

I have tried editing the profile.d startup to match [this StackOverflow suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27613209/how-to-automatically-start-tmux-on-ssh-session), I have tried changing the SSH ClientAlive to 60 and 10 (plus systemd restart), I've tried changing logind.conf to `KillUserProcesses=no` (uncommenting that line with systemd restart and OS restart), and I've tried starting a separate tmux session (session 1) from the session that we get when we login (session 0) and both sessions are terminated upon SSH disconnect. None of those changes have produced desirable behavior.

Has anyone else encountered this issue and found a workaround?

Comment: For debugging purposes, run `screen` while in the session and check if you are not affected by disconnection. and verify if your longterm process did what it should be done

Comment: I ran the task inside `screen` inside `tmux` and `screen` (along with the task) was terminated upon SSH timeout.

Comment: but then in fact, there is something wrong configured. the only thing additional is, retry the same within screen but run `command & ` if still gets killed, then imho the server hardening is to strong and needs to be adjusted.

Comment: `nohup` and `&` have no effect. All processes are still terminated upon SSH killing the connection.

Comment: edit `~/.tmux.conf` and try adding `set -g detach-on-destroy off` - may a other try